# Forward IP/Port Traffic to a different IP Address

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-server-2008, packet

We run a lot of Game Servers, where the connecting players use an IPv4 address to connect to the server, add it to favorites, etc. Unfortunately, when a particular IP address is null routed due to a DDoS attack (frequent) this server is basically offline for 24 hours.

I started look into forwarding traffic from one IP/Port to another IP/Port, but unfortunately this is not possible with UDP traffic on Windows Server.

Is it possible using C++/C# to forward traffic coming in on one Static IP address to another Static IP Address? The idea is to make software a packet router of sorts, except in the case of one address being null routed, it could automatically switch to a different IP.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that your IP address is null routed? If that's the case, then by whom? And why? DDoS attack on your server shouldn't cause it to become null routed, no?

Comment: Also, how is the software router going to help? If I understand correctly, you aren't receiving the packets. So how can you forward them?

Comment: Our machines have large blocks of Static IPs on each one. Our datacenter automatically null routes IP addresses when they receive a DDoS attack.

Comment: Basically my software would reroute the traffic to the normal destination IP/Port until the IP was nullrouted, then it would start routing to a backup IP/Port.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to just use the netsh command line options for TCP. I couldn't find a working solution for UDP unfortunately.